# Designing an electronic product for the american market, need to find a DC to DC converter with FCC certification

Tags: fcc

Can someone please explain the basics of FCC certification for electronic products, my boss has just dropped this task on me to find a fcc approved dc to dc converter for our product .

Does FCC only apply to finished products or can it also apply to individual components. I really know very little other than it is a test of the electrical emissions from a product.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The FCC ruling applies to finished products, in terms of broadband EMI emissions, which normally means it has to be in a metal enclosure. This includes power cord and any other cables that are part of its assembly. It sounds like you need to download or order FCC documentation to get the fine details.

Comment: *Some* DC to DC converters have been tested against the FCC limits and show that they radiate below those limits. The first thing I would to is start looking at DC to DC converters and quit complaining about your boss. Start looking at datasheets

Answer (score 3):

In round numbers, FCC cert applies to the finished product.  Although many switching power supplies come with FCC cert to Class A or B, this does not guarantee that a finished product will meet the rules because of radiated or conducted noise coming from other devices within the product.

The basics are that you build a prototype and send it to a certified testing lab.  The lab does the tests and gives you a report telling you where it passed and where it failed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FCC_Declaration_of_Conformity

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_47_CFR_Part_15

Comment: I’m looking at a DC to DC component that has IEC certification, is that relatively similar to FCC standards, also I’m only looking to pass class B standard of FCC, by the way thanks for the help

Comment: How big?  Watts?  Input voltage?

Comment: https://www.recom-power.com/pdf/Innoline/R-78Wxx-0.5.pdf   here is a link to the datasheet, its a 12vd to 3v3dc converter 500mA, part number R-78W3.3-0.5, IEC/EN-60950 Certified, not sure what you meant by how big.